# GCC not able to locate files in the directory

Tags: c, gcc

Below is the script that runs `gcc`:
build_hello_tf.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET_DIRECTORY="$(pwd)/src/addons/tensorflow/"
echo ${TARGET_DIRECTORY}
gcc -L${TARGET_DIRECTORY} hello_tf.c
ls ${TARGET_DIRECTORY}
```

Here is it's output:

```
/home/karl/dev/node/tensorflow/src/addons/tensorflow/
gcc: error: hello_tf.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
hello_tf.c  src
```

It looks like `gcc` is not able to locate the source file in the directory.

Comment: -L is the library search path. Source files are not searched there. You have to name them with the full path.

Comment: @manni66 Alright, I will do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments :

> -L is the library search path. Source files are not searched there. You have to name them with the full path.